# margin between two select box

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have two select box one by one like below. And my prob is I would like to  give some space (margin) in between this select box.

```
     import Select from '@mui/material/Select'
      
       <FormControl>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Roles</InputLabel>
        <Select label="Roles" name="roles">
          {roles.map(role => (
            <MenuItem key={role} value={role}>
              {role}
            </MenuItem>
                ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>

      <FormControl>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Org</InputLabel>
        <Select label="Org" name="org">
          {orgs.map(org => (
            <MenuItem key={org} value={org}>
              {org}
            </MenuItem>
                ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
```

[image]

I tried few ways but not working. Anyway to override the css here.
I'm new react and css please give me suggestion.

Comment: What did you try exactly? Maybe add a `className` for the FormControl and then a `margin-bottom` with your css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap all form controls with [Mui `Stack` component](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-stack/).

Use the `spacing` prop to set the exact space you need between the components.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nesting selector for the className MuiSelect

```css
selectMargin: {
  "& .MuiSelect": {
    margin: "0px 5px"
  }
}
```

Notice that use className here:

```
className={classes.selectMargin}
```